# PHP SQL registration form

Tags: php, html, sql, registration

I am attempting a registration form that saves the data into a sql db. I'm not doing form validation just yet as what is most troubling me is getting this stuff onto sql. I'd appreciate any advice!!

I have a form.php file that should be doing the hard work. When I submit my form, at this point, I get a blank screen and nothing loads into the database.

```
<?php
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cell = $_POST['cell'];
$experience = $_POST['experience'];
$ip = $_POST['ip'];

$password = md5($_POST['password']);

$connection = msql_connect(localhost, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
$db = mysql_select_db(registration,$connection);    

mysql_query("INSERT INTO userTable (fname,lname,password,email,cell,experience,ip) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$password', '$email', '$cell', '$experience', '$ip')")
    or die (mysql_error());

echo "Thank you for your registration";


?>
```

And I have an html file that contains this:

```
            <form method = "post" action = "form.php">
            <h2>User Information</h2>

            <div><label>First Name:</label>
                <input type = "text" name = "fname"></div>
            <div><label>Last Name:</label>
                <input type = "text" name = "lname"></div>
            <div><label>Password:</label>
                <input type = "password" name = "password"></div>
            <div><label>Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email"></div>
            <div><label>Cellphone:</label>
                <input type="text" name="cell"></div>
                <input type="hidden" name="ip" value='<?php echo $IP ?>'/>
            <h2>What Is Your Experience Mountain Biking?</h2>
            <p><input type="radio" name="experience" value="n00b"
                checked>n00b
                <input type="radio" name="experience" value="intermediate">Intermediate
                <input type="radio" name="experience" value="extreme">Extreme                   
                </p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"></p>
        </form>
```

Finally, I have a sql database (I'm running xampp locally) called "registration"
The table I've created is called "userTable" and it contains 8 fields including ID (auto incrementing) and the 7 other values I've included up top. Any idea what the heck I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why do so many questions still refer to `mysql_` functions? Why don't you use `mysqli_` functions? Also `$connection = msql_connect(localhost, USERNAME, PASSWORD);` is a typo. There is no `msql_connect()` function. Not to mention the sql injection attacks!

Comment: white screen of death = error display off. turn it on and see what you get

Comment: i recommend adding error_reporting(E_ALL); to the top of the script to make sure all errors and issues are reported. Once that is done, we can see further why things arent working.

Comment: I've added the error reporting and get nothing but white. I also fixed my typo. I will deal with injection attacks when I can actually get this to update..

Comment: @RossSmithII Because if you google for 'php connect to mysql tutorial' you still get loads of results from old tutorials that haven't been updated in years. If you are just starting out, you don't know any better...

Comment: Not to mention, the textbooks that I have ( no older than 12 months) don't mention mysqli. Sorry!!

Comment: if you are still getting the blank screen, try putting "or die (mysql_error())" next to mysql_connect() and mysql_select_db() call. i am not sure if localhost is without quotes just for demo purposes.

Comment: done, still blank. i tried this in a few browsers to see if something was acting up but no change

Comment: I would double check your connection information.  I made my first form a like a year ago and had the same issue.  I'm also curious about the $ip as could never find a script that worked for me.

Comment: I used <?php
$IP = $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR];
?> to get the ip and it seemed to work, because at one point it was populating into a text input I mistakenly placed. I suppose this may be a connection issue...blah

Comment: Your code is a prime candidate for SQL injection attacks from the web, which would ruin your day. With a specially crafted first name string, an attacker could make you delete your database. Please see http://bobby-tables.com for how SQL injection works, and http://bobby-tables.com/php.html for examples on the safe way to do your inserts.

Comment: @RossSmithII - the reasons so many questions still ask about the old `mysql_xx` functions are (a) lots of people are having to work with old PHP code that already uses it, (b) most of the tutorials on the web still use it, and (c) the deprecation notes on the manual page haven't been there that long. Yes, we should be telling people not to use it, but don't be surprised by them asking. (in fact, be grateful they asked here, so they can at least be told)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Solved my own problem


<?php
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cell = $_POST['cell'];
$experience = $_POST['experience'];
$ip = $_POST['ip'];

$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($fname);
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string($lname);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

$servername="localhost";
$username="user";
$conn=  mysql_connect($servername,$username, password)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("registration",$conn);
$sql="insert into userTable (fname,lname,password,email,cell,experience,ip) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$password', '$email', '$cell', '$experience', '$ip')";

$result=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());          
print "<h1>you have registered sucessfully</h1>";


echo "Thank you for your registration to the ";

mysql_close($connection);
```

?>

Comment: $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']) and you can save some line.

Answer (score 2):

What is the problem?

1) The problem is that it does INSERT query each time you load this page - mean each time it inserts empty values. Why?

Simply because there's no condition that checks if all fields has been posted, so instead of:

```
<?php

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cell = $_POST['cell'];
$experience = $_POST['experience'];
$ip = $_POST['ip'];
```

You should check if `$_POST` super-global has some keys.
So before doing any queries - first of all check if `$_POST` isn't empty

```
<?php

//This means that user did submit the form
if ( !empty($_POST) ){

  //all your stuff goes here
}

?>
<html>
.....
</html>
```

2) Are you sure you are in control of your code? Apparently not.

You MUST check if some function returned `TRUE` and then make following actions relying on it's one.

For example, are you sure that `mysql_query("your sql query")` was succeed at?

3) Enable error_reporting to E_ALL, so just put `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of your page, like this:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

So that you can always debug your script "on fly"

4) You are doing everything to make this code hard to maintain, Why? 
Look at this:

```
<?php

//Debug mode:
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//Sure you want to show some error if smth went wrong:
$errors = array(); 

/**
 * 
 * @return TRUE if connection established 
 * FALSE on error
 */
function connect(){

 $connection = mysql_connect(localhost, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
 $db = mysql_select_db(registration,$connection);    

 if (!$connection || !$db ){
   return false; 
 } else {
   return true;
 }
}


//So this code will run if user did submit the form:
if (!empty($_POST)){

 //Connect sql server:
 if ( !connect() ){
   $errors[] = "Can't establish link to MySQL server";
 }

 $fname = $_POST['fname'];
 $lname = $_POST['lname'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $cell = $_POST['cell'];
 $experience = $_POST['experience'];
 //Why post ip? not smth like $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']...
 $ip = $_POST['ip'];

 $password = md5($_POST['password']);

 //No error at this point - means that it successfully connected to SQL server: 
 if ( empty($errors) ){

  //let's prevent sql injection:

  $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($fname);
  //Please do this for all of them..
 }



//Now we should try to INSERT the vals:

$query = "INSERT INTO `userTable` (`fname`,`lname`,`password`,`email`,`cell`,`experience`,`ip`) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$password', '$email', '$cell', '$experience', '$ip')";

//So try it:
if ( !mysql_query($query) ){
   // 
   //die (mysql_error());
   $errors[] = "Can't insert the vals";
} else {
   //Or on success:
   print ("Thank you for your registration");
   //or you can do redirect to some page, like this:

  //header('location: /thanks.php');
}


}

?>

<form method="post">
            <h2>User Information</h2>

            <div><label>First Name:</label>
                <input type = "text" name = "fname"></div>
            <div><label>Last Name:</label>
                <input type = "text" name = "lname"></div>
            <div><label>Password:</label>
                <input type = "password" name = "password"></div>
            <div><label>Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email"></div>
            <div><label>Cellphone:</label>
                <input type="text" name="cell"></div>
                <input type="hidden" name="ip" value='<?php echo $IP ?>'/>
            <h2>What Is Your Experience Mountain Biking?</h2>
            <p><input type="radio" name="experience" value="n00b"
                checked>n00b
                <input type="radio" name="experience" value="intermediate">Intermediate
                <input type="radio" name="experience" value="extreme">Extreme                   
                </p>

            <?php if ( !empty($errors) ) : ?>

            <?php foreach($errors as $error): ?> 
             <p><b><?php echo $error; ?></b></p>
            <?php endforeach; ?> 
             <?php endif; ?>


            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"></p>
        </form>
```

Comment: I like the way you set it up, I may use this in the future.